# CRUDlex not working when add new table in yaml

Tags: php, symfony, crud, silex

i try to find a faster way to generate UI for existing database, CRUD, composer way, using symfony component.

found [CRUDlex](https://github.com/philiplb/CRUDlex). Doing install with composer, also setup [CRUDlex sample](https://github.com/philiplb/CRUDlexSample) 
it works fine, until i m add new table definition in sample [crud.yml](https://github.com/philiplb/CRUDlexSample/blob/master/crud.yml)

```
category:
  label: Category
  table: category
  fields:
    name:
      type: text
      label: Name
      required: true
      unique: true
```

what ever table added in yml, it's always throw error similar to this when access     http://localhost/crudlex/web/category

```
InvalidFieldNameException in AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 71: An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `category` `category` WHERE deleted_at IS NULL':
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'deleted_at' in 'where clause'
```

complete error message please check screenshot below
[image: CRUDlex Error]

crudlex always asking "id" and 'deleted_at'

the code is same as CRUDled sample [index.php](https://github.com/philiplb/CRUDlexSample/blob/master/web/index.php)

```
    $loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

    //$loader->add('CRUDlex', __DIR__.'/../../CRUDlex/src');
    $app = new Silex\Application();

    $app['debug'] = true;

    $app->register(new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(
        'dbs.options' => array(
            'default' => array(
                'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
                'dbname'    => 'dbname',
                'user'      => 'root',
                'password'  => '',
                'charset'   => 'utf8',
            )
        ),
    ));
    $app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider());

    $dataFactory = new CRUDlex\MySQLDataFactory($app['db']);
    $app->register(new CRUDlex\ServiceProvider(), array(
        'crud.file' => __DIR__ . '/../crud.yml',
        'crud.datafactory' => $dataFactory
    ));
    $app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider());

    //$app['crud.layout'] = 'layout.twig';
    $app->mount('/', new CRUDlex\ControllerProvider());

    $app->match('/', function() use ($app) {
        return $app->redirect($app['url_generator']->generate('crudList', array('entity' => 'library')));
    })->bind('homepage');

    $app->run();
```

And folder structure

```
vendor
web
    > .htaccess
    > index.php
composer.json
crud.yml
```

Note: I m totally new to silex and symfony2 component ^_^
Thank you, any suggest really appreciated

Comment: your database is out of date to your schema.  You need to update it somehow (I'm symfony not silex I'm afraid so my knowledge of that is lacking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing (at least) one of the required meta fields:

- created_at (datetime, not null): When the record was created
- updated_at (datetime, not null): When the record was edited the last time
- version (int, not null): The version of the record, increments with each edit
- deleted_at (datetime): If not null: When the record was (soft-) deleted

The complete table creation SQL in your case would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Thank you Phil! ah i see, is it possible to disabled that meta fields?
it will look weird if all table has metafields

Comment: Hi, disabling them is currently not possible I'm afraid. But this feature is on the plate: https://github.com/philiplb/CRUDlex/issues/11 https://github.com/philiplb/CRUDlex/issues/14 https://github.com/philiplb/CRUDlex/issues/38  -- Never had a real use case for this feature, hence it is not implemented yet. :) Yes, it might look "weird" but we use it actually always as this data is later on usefull and disk space is cheap. :) But I agree that you might not be in the position to change the existing schema of your DB.